# Extract or copy a string value from declaration code in Eclipse (IDE feature)

Tags: java, eclipse, string, ide

Assume the following **String** declarations:

```
final String WAY_TO_JINGLE = "all the way";
String vehicleName = Transport.getVehicleName("Santa Claus");

String example =
    "Jingle bells, jingle bells, " +
    "jingle " + WAY_TO_JINGLE + '.' + System.lineSeparator() +
    "Oh! what fun it is to ride " +
    "\tIn a one-horse open " + vehicleName + '.';
```

Is there a feature in **or** plugin for *Eclipse* which would allow me to copy to clipboard, the declared string from this code?

For example, using it on the declaration of `example` would put the following text in clipboard (assuming I entered *"sleigh"* as the value for `vehicleName`):

```
Jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the way.
Oh! what fun it is to ride     In a one-horse open sleigh.
```

It should do the following:

- Get known constant or variable values from their declarations.
- Show a dialog form to fill up values for unknown variables, *possibly pre-filling best guess or variable name itself*.
- Parse the escape characters in the string literal.
- Be aware of System tools like `lineSeparator()` method and `"line.separator"` property.

Comment: For one thing, `System.lineSeparator()` isn't a compile-time constant.

Comment: Do you know about Scrapbook Page? From the drop-down File menu ,click on the New button, select Other. Then select Java ->Java Run/Debug -> Scrapbook Page. Then click Next. Enter any file name. You can add java code snippets and select them and evaluate them directly.

Comment: @chrylis It doesn't matter, since I want an IDE feature. The feature could populate the line separators matching the IDE's host platform. Anyway, it's a minor detail. @ElliottFrisch That's something I didn't know about, thanks `:)` It comes close to what I really want as described in my question, although it's a little more work (_create a scrapbook file, copy code, paste, manually enter variable values, add a return statement, ensure code is syntactically correct, select all, click Display_). I would like to have something easier (_just a couple of clicks_), but this is useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such a feature or plugin (or it is undiscovered by me). The closest I can get is by using the *Scrapbook* feature in *Eclipse* (many thanks to [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch)).

1. In Eclipse, click **File > New > Other** or press <kbd>Ctrl N</kbd>.
2. Type in *scrapbook* and select *Java > Java Run/Debug >* **Scrapbook Page**.
3. Click **Next**, select a folder, enter a file name, and click **Finish**.
4. Once in the scrapbook, paste the code snippet. Replace all method references with actual strings:

   ```
   final String WAY_TO_JINGLE = "all the way";
   String vehicleName = "sleigh";

   String example =
       "Jingle bells, jingle bells, " +
       "jingle " + WAY_TO_JINGLE + '.' + '\n' +
       "Oh! what fun it is to ride " +
       "\tIn a one-horse open " + vehicleName + '.';
   ```
5. Then add a return statement:

   ```
   return example;
   ```
6. Select all of it, and click the **Display** button or press <kbd>Ctrl Shift D</kbd>.

If there are errors, the error descriptions will be added *before* the selected text. Correct the errors, delete the descriptions, and try the last step again.

```
The method lineSeparator() is undefined for the type System
final String WAY_TO_JINGLE = "all the way";
```

If there are no errors, the returned value will be added *after* the selected text along with the return type.

```
return example;
(java.lang.String) Jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the way.
Oh! what fun it is to ride  In a one-horse open sleigh.
```